# Handler missing on module 'awslambda' when code uploaded as zip file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have this code in a file called awslambda.js

```
console.log('Loading function');

exports.bullion = function(event, context) {
    //console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    var message = event.Records[0].Sns.Message;
    console.log('From SNS:', message);
    context.succeed(message);
};
```

I zip it up so it looks like this:

```
bullion $ unzip -l target/bullion-dev-for-lambda.zip
Archive:  target/bullion-dev-for-lambda.zip
  Length     Date   Time    Name
 --------    ----   ----    ----
      268  02-05-16 10:39   awslambda.js
 --------                   -------
      268                   1 file
```

I upload it to AWS Lambda and configure the Handler to be

```
awslambda.bullion
```

I test the function and I get

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Handler 'bullion' missing on module 'awslambda'"
}
```

If I type the same code into a Lambda function it works!  What's the special case with the zip file upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be that 'awslambda' is already a module in the Lambda environment.  When I change the file from awslambda.js to bullionAwsLambda.js, and change the Handler accordingly, it works.

A sneaky one that lost me a lot of time!

Answer (score 1):

The most common mistake with this is that you zip the folder, then instead of this:

```
zip contains:  
 - awslambda.js  
 - otherFiles.js
```

You now get this:

```
zip contains:  
 - foldername/  
   - awslambda.js  
   - otherFiles.js
```

As in, the folder is in the zip (containing the code) instead of the contents of the folder. The folder itself should not be zipped, so that the awslambda.js file is in the root of the zip file.

To fix this: do not compress the folder (right-click -> compress), but open the folder, select all files and then right-click -> compress.

Comment: Thanks Luc.  I had the folder structure correct, it just seems that awslambda is a module in the Lambda runtime env!